# In Craft 2.5, how can you sort the entry index page by a custom field?

Tags: entries, sorting

I recently updated a very large site to Craft 2.5. One of the great new features is the ability to **view custom fields as columns** on the entry index page.

Previously, I used the [DashCols](https://github.com/mmikkel/DashCols-Craft) plugin to view those columns, but DashCols was rendered obsolete by the Craft 2.5 release. However, there was one other feature that DashCols has, which Craft 2.5 *doesn't* have...

**How can you sort by custom fields on the entry index page?**

[image: Entry Index Page]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, the only way to add custom fields to the sortable attributes is to [write a custom plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) which makes use of the [`modifyEntrySortableAttributes`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySortableAttributes) hook, e.g.:

```
public function modifyEntrySortableAttributes(&$attributes)
{
    $attributes['yourCustomFieldHandle'] = Craft::t('Label');
    $attributes['anotherCustomField'] = Craft::t('Another label');
}
```

The `modifyEntrySortableAttributes` method would go into your plugin's primary class.

Apart from custom fields, it's also possible to add other attributes in this manner, such as `authorId` (to sort on author) or `typeId` (to sort on entry type).

It's also possible to *remove* a sortable attribute:

```
unset($attributes['postDate']);
```

There are corresponding hooks for adding sortable attributes to category, asset and user index tables, see [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#element-hooks) for details.

One gotcha to note is that since the sortable attributes are *source agnostic* (i.e. they're the same across all sections), any custom field you add to the sortable attributes should ideally exist for *all your entry types*, as attempting to sort on a custom field that doesn't exist for the entries in the current index table will throw an error.

Moving into opinionated waters here, but to close: While the Customizable Element Indexes (CEI) is a great thing to have in core (and with a brilliant UI), I personally feel there's room for improvement; especially pertaining to sortable attributes. On that note, there are a few relevant feature requests:

- http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7274973-add-a-source-parameter-to-modifyentrysortableattr
- http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/10943841-sortable-custom-columns
- http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/11533941-sort-filter-entries-by-entry-type
- http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/10579029-add-custom-fields-in-customizable-element-indexes

**EDIT**

I just published a new plugin which will add any (sortable) custom field or meta value in any given element index to the index' sortable attributes:   https://github.com/mmikkel/CpSortableCustomColumns-Craft
The plugin is source aware, so it should avoid the issue with sorting on non-existing fields (as described above) in most cases. Like most Control Panel-specific plugins, it's basically one big hack – but it works until we can have better sorting abilities in core. Hopefully it's useful to someone!

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks Mats! Bonus points for the DIY plugin! :)

Comment: Is it possible to sort by category using modifyEntrySortableAttributes? If not, is it possible some other way?