# Sort CP Entries by Category

Tags: plugin-development, entries, categories, plugins, control-panel

I know it's possible, using `modifyEntrySortableAttributes`, to sort the CP entries table by a custom field, when that field is a number, string, date/time, or bool. Would it be possible to sort a CP table by category? If not, is there another hook, or some other way I could implement this functionality?

Sorting by number, string, date/time, bool:
[In Craft 2.5, how can you sort the entry index page by a custom field?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13472/in-craft-2-5-how-can-you-sort-the-entry-index-page-by-a-custom-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for but it works. You can change the `Craft.BaseElementIndex`and the [updateElements](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/resources/js/craft.js#L2081) function. All you have to do is to change the destination path to a custom controller

```
Craft.BaseElementIndex.prototype.updateElements = function()
{
    // Ignore if we're not fully initialized yet
    if (!this.initialized)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.setIndexBusy();

    var params = this.getViewParams();

    Craft.postActionRequest('yourPluginHandle/controllerName/getElements', params, $.proxy(function(response, textStatus)
    {
        this.setIndexAvailable();

        if (textStatus == 'success')
        {
            this._updateView(params, response);
        }
        else
        {
            Craft.cp.displayError(Craft.t('An unknown error occurred.'));
        }

    }, this));
},
```

Then you can create a custom controller that extends the `ElementIndexController` and can use it's [function](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/controllers/ElementIndexController.php#L102) that calls the private function `_getElementResponseData`. All the elements that should be displayed are received in

```
$responseData['html'] = $this->_elementType->getIndexHtml(
    $this->_criteria,
    $disabledElementIds,
    $this->_viewState, <-- this is the important variable
    $this->_sourceKey,
    $this->_context,
    $includeContainer,
    $showCheckboxes
);
```

The sort order is defined [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/elementtypes/BaseElementType.php#L203)

```
if ($sortableAttributes)
{
    $order = (!empty($viewState['order']) && isset($sortableAttributes[$viewState['order']])) ? $viewState['order'] : ArrayHelper::getFirstKey($sortableAttributes);
    $sort  = (!empty($viewState['sort']) && in_array($viewState['sort'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $viewState['sort'] : 'asc';

    $criteria->order = preg_replace('/^(.*?)(?:\s+(?:asc|desc))?(,.*)?$/i', "$1 {$sort}$2", $order);
}
```

As you can easily see it checks if the `$viewState['order']` is empty or not. This variable is defined in your controller so all you have to do is to check if your javascript returns a `order` variable, get the field by handle and check if the field handle is `instance of BaseRelationField`. If so, you'll unset the variable in the `$viewState` and change the `$criteria` by yourself.

Unfortunately the query is executed in `BaseElementType.php` so you have to implement a way to sort by eager loading elements (which I doubt is possible by default) or you can create a custom `element type` just for this case and overwrite the entire `getIndexHtml()` function.

It might sound like a lot of work and effort but honestly it can be done in 5-10 minutes... I've done the same once within no time. It's 99% copy paste. Maybe someone  has a better answer but since there is no real event or hook I'm not sure if there is a real clean way to do this. Of course this is only for Craft 2. In Craft 3 it's much easier since there are more events and hooks and you can replace classes more easy.

Another approach would be to overwrite the entire `BaseElementIndex` class with [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28979-how-to-override-yii-core-classes/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254106/yii-how-to-override-extend-core-file). But I never did that so I can't give much advice

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly the type of work around I'm needing. This all makes sense, but how exactly do you alter the criteria to order by category? Would I need to write custom SQL outside of the ElementAPI?

Comment: That's the question. I searched a little bit but the `Elements` `getEagerLoadingMap` includes the eager loading elements directly into the query. So I don't think you can include the sort order directly into the `ElementCriteriaModel`. Thus you'll need to create a custom element type in order to overwrite the entire `getIndexHtml` and reorder the entries before `$criteria->find()` is executed. I searched the last 30 minutes but every question of this type is unanswered at stack exchange. I think you have to create your own `Query` with `$db = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);`

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder, join Crafts `relation` table with the correct field Id on your entry id and order your entries by the title. I can provide a working example in about 12h if you are not able to make it. Edit: you can see how to join related entries here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22833/querying-channel-entries-hits-memory-limit/22844#22844

Comment: Haven't actually tried this yet, but I know it would work. Accepting answer.